# Databound MSChart not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have an application that is updating a datatable at periodic intervals, and I have that datatable bound to the chart as the data source.

```
    private DataTable seriesData = new DataTable();

    //in load handler
    seriesData.Columns.Add("TagName", typeof(string));
    seriesData.Columns.Add("XValue", typeof(DateTime));
    seriesData.Columns.Add("YValue", typeof(double));
    chart.DataSource = seriesData;
    chart.DataBindCrossTable(seriesData.DefaultView, "TagName", "XValue", "YValue", "");
```

Then the datasource is filled with data at the specified intervals

```
    var newRow = seriesData.NewRow();
    newRow["XValue"] = ts;
    newRow["YValue"] = Convert.ToDouble(tag.Value);
    newRow["TagName"] = tag.Name;
    //add new row to dataset
    seriesData.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

The problem is, the chart does not automatically update when the datasource is updated with new data.
I thought it needed to be refreshed using  `chart.DataBind();` but that didn't refresh the chart.  I also tried using `chart.Invalidate();` but that didn't work either.  I did verify the datatable has data in it, and it is changing in the dataview attached to the chart.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I found the answer.  So each time I want to update the chart I have to clear the series collection and call DataBindCrossTable again.

```
    chart.Series.Clear();
    chart.DataBindCrossTable(seriesData.DefaultView, "TagName", "XValue", "YValue", "");
```

Even though this seems like an expensive operation each time an update needs to occur, I see no other way of updating a bound chart.